# How to show that an element is in a vector?

Tags: notation, vectors

I'm wondering what the correct notation is to say that $x$ is in a vector $v$.

I mean something like $x \in \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
z\\
\end{array}
\right)$ (Not sure if this is correct)

Comment: I do not think that is standard notation, if I encountered it, I would not be able to guess what it meant.  If you have a vector $\vec v=(v_1, \cdots, v_n)$ then you could speak of $x=v_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: Using dot products is probably more standard: $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ z \end{pmatrix} \cdot \hat i = x$.